# Pasting 2 columns to a new variable in a ordered format

Tags: r

I have 2 columns of data (x1, x2) and they have common and dissimilar data. I want to paste the the 2 columns together, separate by + sign, to a new variable (x3) so the data is in order i.e. the lowest numbered/character element always appears before the separator (+). For example this is what I want

```
ID    x1          x2         x3
01    x*01:02     x*01:03    x*01:02+x*01:03
02    x*01:03     x*01:02    x*01:02+x*01:03
03    x*02:01     x*08:01    x*02:01+x*08:01
04    x*08:01     x*02:01    x*02:01+x*08:01
```

when i run

```
df$x3 = paste(df$x1, df$x2, sep="+")
```

x3 for IDs 01 to 01 appears as

```
x3
x*01:02+x*01:03
x*01:03+x*01:02
x*02:01+x*08:01
x*08:01+x*02:01
```

Comment: Is this a time column?  What is the criteria to use which one is lower

Comment: No its not a time column. The criteria is the lowest digit element eg. x*01:01 is less than x*01:03

Comment: `01:01` is not numeric because of `:`  Are you using the `01` after the `:` or before the `:`

Comment: I'm using 01 before the colon

Comment: If you are using 01 befor ethe colon, then `01:02` and `01:03` cannot be differentiated

Comment: Before and after the colon matter i.e.01:01 is less than 01:02, but 02:01 is greater than both 01:01 and 01:02. Also 02:10 is greater than 02:01 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you describe, an alphabetical sort should work. You can do this across each row as such:

```
df$x3 <- apply(df[,2:3], 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "+"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mixedsort`

```
library(gtools)
apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) paste(mixedsort(x), collapse = "+"))
#[1] "x*01:02+x*01:03" "x*01:02+x*01:03" "x*02:01+x*08:01" "x*02:01+x*08:01"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, x1 = c("x*01:02", "x*01:03", "x*02:01", 
"x*08:01"), x2 = c("x*01:03", "x*01:02", "x*08:01", "x*02:01"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of `x1` and `x2` is as you described, i.e. two sets of two digits separated by `:`, you could split `x1` and `x2` into two columns by `:`, then use standard numerical comparisons to align results in the order you see fit, and finally turn the output back into strings if you need to. Would that work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Basically after the paste function I need another function to order the x3 data